# Are there any differences in how I am checking props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am always looking into writing code in different and more legible ways, and have been writing my if statements in my React-Redux application slightly different recently. Are there any functional differences in writing my functions this way? In this sample, in a `Login` container,  `componentWillReceiveProps` checks to see if a user's identity is defined in the Redux store (accessed via mapStateToProps.) If `nextProps.isLoggedIn` is `true`, then the user will be pushed to the root route in my application.

From what I can tell, the two code snippets written below act in the same manner, but I am curious to know if there are any edges cases in which they are do not function in synonymous ways.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isLoggedIn) {
      browserHistory.push('/');
    }
  }
```

versus

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    !!(nextProps.isLoggedIn) && browserHistory.push('/');
  }
```

`connect` portion of my container:

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.identity,
  }),
  { login },
)(Login);
```

And in my reducer, the default param for `identity` is `null`. When the user successfully logs in, the `identity` value is updated to an object that is returned as a response from the auth backend.

Comment: The `!!` isn't necessary in your usage.

Comment: Darn, you're right. I will modify my question so that it doesn't use a boolean as the default param in the reducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical operators `&&` and `||` use [short-circuiting evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning that they won't evaluate the second expression if the first expression evaluates to a certain value.

- With `&&`, the second expression won't be evaluated if the first expression is **[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**.
- With `||`, the second expression won't be evaluated if the first expression is **[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)**.

They can often be used in order to eliminate `if` statements and make your code more functional and less imperative.

---

In your specific case, `null` is a falsy value, so:

```
if (nextProps.isLoggedIn) {
  browserHistory.push('/');
}
```

Has the exact same output as:

```
nextProps.isLoggedIn && browserHistory.push('/');
```

[`if` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) execute a statement if the provided expression is truthy, so they use the same rules to evaluate. The primary difference with using `if`, is that you can evaluate statements instead of only expressions. For example, you can't declare a `var` in the second part of `&&` or `||`.

Comment: Good summary. Also, while it's true that you can't declare a var, I often include lines like this in a shorthand if statement: `var x; y || (x=y)`.